# Changing window background uicolor

Tags: ios

Does anyone know why the uiwindow's background color does not change when I apply say blue to it?? How can I check if applied it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you displaying any view controllers? you won't see the colour of the window if you are showing view controllers over it

To test the colour of the window, add

```
self.window.rootViewController = nil;
```

before makeKeyAndVisible in appDidFinishLaunching